# Extracting zip file to Amazon s3 bucket in Django not working

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-models

Django setting.py has following

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'apps.storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/media/'
```

model looks like this

```
class UploadFile(models.Model):
    def get_upload_path(self, filename):
        return os.path.join("documentsUploaded",filename)
    upload_location = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, max_length=300)
    text_location = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_path, max_length=300)
```

This works fine and the file gets uploaded to s3 bucket as expected.

So, now when i try to extract a zip file

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path)
zf.extractall(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,"documentsUploaded"))
```

the files gets extracted to ... /meadia/ location in server but not to S3 bucket.

What is that i am missing here? or is there a different way to extract .zip files onto s3 from Django?